# Evaluating the limit of $\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $x\to 0^+$

Tags: calculus, limits

What is

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)\quad\text{ where }\quad f(x) =\left( \frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}$$

? The problem suggests to use a Taylor expansion, but it is not clear to me *what* to expand.

Answer (score 5):

By the Taylor expansion of the sine function (that is an entire function) we have that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ behaves like $1-\frac{x^2}{6}$ in a right neighbourhood of zero, hence:

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}&=&\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\\&=&\lim_{y\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{6y^2}\right)^{y^2}\\&=&\lim_{z\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{6z}\right)^{z}=\large\color{red}{e^{-\frac{1}{6}}}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Oh, it meant by using Taylor expansion on (sinx / x) not the whole f(x) function. It was greatly helpful, thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnLee: you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Another slightly different approach is to write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x^2}&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log \frac{\sin x}{x}}{x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\log(1-\frac16x^2+O(x^4))}{x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-\frac16x^2+O(x^4)}{x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(-\frac16+O(x^2)\right) \right)\\\\
&=e^{-1/6}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Note: you can bring the limit inside the $\exp$ function because it's continuous over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @rubik Yes, I exploited that fact.  Thank you for the comment.